# combine two select statements into one csv file?

Tags: sql

I would like to be able to output this in a csv file

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQglV.jpg

The first row comes from one select statement, and the rest of the rows below come from a second select statement. Is this possible?

Comment: union queries are your friend.

Comment: Sure - just `UNION` them.

Comment: Thanks, that was super easy